# How to display Instagram photos on the website

Tags: php, instagram, bitrix

I want to display instagram photos on my website, I have already done it 
thanks to this tutorial https://www.codeofaninja.com/2015/01/display-instagram-feed-website.html

But I want to know is it possible to make popup as it is on instagram with the posibility to leave comment or to like a post on instagram, but not leaving the website?

Comment: You could create an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: Just go to [Instagram's Developer Documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding)